# How do I use different package versions from different folders without pipenv?

Tags: python, shared-libraries, versioning, dependency-management, python-poetry

My Project's structure looks like the following:

```
Python-Project
  +-__init__.py
  +-app.py
External Libraries
  +-shared_library
  +-static_utils
    +-shared_library
```

`app.py` imports both `shared_library` and `static_utils`, but the `shared_library` packages are of different versions.
How can I tell python to use a specific `shared_library` version when running a `static_utils` function?

This seems like a classic dependency hell issue and I wonder what approaches I can take to fix this.

**P.S.** I'm using poetry and a private repository.

Comment: This is not possible in Python at all. You can only have one version of a package. Some discussion about this is here: https://discuss.python.org/t/installing-multiple-versions-of-a-package/4862